# Jquery - hide() then fadeIn() then fadeOut() is there a cleaner way?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve some animation using jQuery. I have it working but I'm 100% sure there is a cleaner better way of doing and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#1-popup").hide(); // Hides the first popup
    $("#2-popup").hide(); // Hides the second popup
    $("#1-trigger").toggle(function () {
        $("#2-popup").fadeOut("slow"); // Hides the second popup just incase its showing
        $("#1-popup").fadeIn("slow"); // Fades in the first popup
    }, function () {
        $("#1-popup").fadeOut("slow"); // Fades out in the first popup
    });


    $("#2-trigger").toggle(function () {
        $("#1-popup").fadeOut("slow"); // Hides the first popup just incase its showing
        $("#2-popup").fadeIn("slow"); // Fades in the second popup
    }, function () {
        $("#2-popup").fadeOut("slow"); // Fades out the second popup
    });
});
```

Its a little messy is there anyway to use an if statement in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about being a bit more generic instead of writing code for every popup itself? :-)

```
<div class="popup" id="popup1">Hi I'm Popup 1</div>
<div class="popup" id="popup2">Hi I'm Popup 2</div>
<a class="trigger" rel="popup1">show popup 1</a>
<a class="trigger" rel="popup2">show popup 2</a>
<script>
var popups = $('.popup').hide();
$('a.trigger').click(function() {
  var popup = $('#'+$(this).attr('rel'));
  popups.not(popup.fadeIn()).fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could move the toggle code into a seperate function and reuse this for the different triggers. This is more just a general refactoring rather than a jQuery specific improvement:

```
bindToggleTriggerAndFadePopups($("#1-trigger"), $("#1-popup"), $("#2-popup"))       
bindToggleTriggerAndFadePopups($("#2-trigger"), $("#2-popup"), $("#1-popup"))       

function bindToggleTriggerAndFadePopups($trigger, $popupToFadeIn, $popupToHide){
    $trigger.toggle(
        function(){
            $popupToHide.fadeOut("slow"); // Hides the first popup just incase its showing
            $popupToFadeIn.fadeIn("slow"); // Fades in the second popup
        },
        function(){
            $popupToFadeIn.fadeOut("slow"); // Fades out the second popup
        });
}
```

Comment: I haven't test this I'm afraid, so I'm not sure why it only works on a double click. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#1-popup,#2-popup').hide(); // Hides the first and second popup

    $('#1-trigger,#2-trigger').toggle(function () {
        var num = parseInt(this.id);

        $('#1-popup,#2-popup').not('#'+num+'-popup').fadeOut('slow'); 
        $('#'+num+'-popup').fadeIn('slow'); 
    }, function () {

        $('#'+num+'-popup').fadeOut('slow'); 
    });

});
```

**WARNING**: you have invalid attribute value for `id` , [refer here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2). With that, you'll get serious problems on some browsers.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the number to work around - good thinking hummmm.

Comment: Thanks for the warning - these are only temp names to make the code easier to explain so they will be changing...